# slicing a string from reverse in python

Tags: python, string, slice

I had a string for example as below

```
i = 'backup_1.2012-12-19.tar.gz'
```

I need to fetch only the `2012-12-19.tar.gz` from the string from the reverse(Because sometimes the string alters like `'backup_2.2012-12-20.tar.gz','backup_3.2012-12-21.tar.gz'`)

So what ever the string is, i need to slice the characters from `2012 to .gz` from reverse 
in python

Can anyone let me know how to do this python

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just take everything after the first `.`?

```
>>> s.split('.', 1)[1]
'2012-12-19.tar.gz'
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
In [160]: i = 'backup_1.2012-12-19.tar.gz'

In [161]: i.partition('.')
Out[161]: ('backup_1', '.', '2012-12-19.tar.gz')

In [162]: i.partition('.')[-1]
Out[162]: '2012-12-19.tar.gz'
```

**EDIT**: If you want to "reverse" the date:

```
In [163]: i.partition('.')[-1].partition('.')[0]
Out[163]: '2012-12-19'

In [164]: i.partition('.')[-1].partition('.')[0].split('-')[::-1]
Out[164]: ['19', '12', '2012']

In [165]: '-'.join(i.partition('.')[-1].partition('.')[0].split('-')[::-1])
Out[165]: '19-12-2012'
```

Comment: You might also need `str.split` to get out the date to reverse it and `str.join` to put the file name back together.

Comment: If you want to split and join, `str.partition` >> `str.split`, if only because it gives you the left, delim and the right. That being said, it works effectively as `str.split(delim, 1)`, so for chopping a string into several parts, `str.split` >> `str.partition`

Comment: Right, but if the date needs to be reversed without messing up the `'.tar.gz'`, you could do

Answer (score 4):

You can use a slice with a negative index:

```
s[-17:]
```

Comment: Which we do, in this case. All the filenames have the exact same, fixed-length format.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ".".join(i.split(".")[1:])
```

this will also work. But Jon's ans is more apt as there you will be doing only two operations.

or do it by following way. This will always return you the string from last even if the string contains more '.' in beginning.

```
".".join(i.split(".")[-3:])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
i = "backup_1.2012-12-19.tar.gz"
z = i[9:26]
print(z)
```

Comment: Hey, could you please add some further explanation on this answer. Btw, what if the file is named `backup_234.2021…`?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.